# Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь вводил данные- они сразу шли в базу данных?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Есть файл php, который связан с базой данных в phpmyadmin. Я пытаюсь заполнить регистрационную форму на сайте- она заполняется, но никуда не отправляется. Как ее отправить в phpmyadmin?

```
    <?php
$dbhost = "localhost"; // Имя хоста БД
$dbusername = "root"; // Пользователь БД
$dbpass = ""; // Пароль к базе
$dbname = "database_rom"; // Имя базы

$dbconnect = mysql_connect ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpass); 
if (!$dbconnect) { echo ("Не могу подключиться к серверу базы данных!"); }

if(@mysql_select_db($dbname)) { echo "Подключение к базе $dbname установлено!"; }
else die ("Не могу подключиться к базе данных $dbname!");

?>
```

Есть база данных в phpmyadmin, и я могу туда ввести данные. Но надо с сайта- а как это сделать? Данные должны вводиться с регистрационной формы.[image: База в phpmyadmin]

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Спортивный сайт
</title>
  <h2 align=center> Спорт- это жизнь! </h2>
<link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<style> 
body 
</style>
<P> <H3 ALIGN=left> Регистрационная форма </H3> 
<h3>Ответьте, пожалуйста, на вопросы:

<FORM> <P> Ваше имя: <INPUT NAME=”name" SIZE=«48">
 <P> Мужчина <INPUT NAME=”gender" TYPE=RADIO VALUE=”male">
 <P> Женщина <INPUT NAME=”gender" TYPE=RADIO VALUE=”female">
 <P> Ваш спорт <INPUT NAME=”sport" TYPE=TEXT>
 <P> Разряд спортсмена <INPUT NAME=”rasryad" TYPE=TEXT>
 <P> Команда <INPUT NAME=”ves" TYPE=TEXT>


Ваша весовая категория?

<input type="checkbox" checked><label>70 кг</label><br>
<input type="checkbox"><label>80 кг</label><br>
<input type="checkbox"><label>100+ кг</label>

 <P> Адрес проживания: <TEXTAREA NAME=”other" COLS=48 ROWS=3></TEXTAREA>
<P> Для подтверждения ввода нажмите на кнопку Отправить. 
<P> Для сброса введенных данных нажмите на кнопку Сбросить. 
<P> <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT><INPUT TYPE=RESET></h3> 
</FORM>
<p align=center>
<img src='download.jpg'>
</p>
<ol> <h1>
<li> Тяжелая атлетика <img src='tyak.jpg' height='150' width='200'>
<li> Теннис <img src='tennis.jpg' height='150' width='200'>
<li> Борьба <img src='1.jpg' height='150' width='200'>
<li> Бокс <img src='box.png' height='150' width='200'></h1> 
</ol>
<button id="getAdvice">Get advice</button>
<div id="advice"></div>
  <script> 
const adviceModule = (() => {
  const advicesArray = ['Чистите зубы каждый день', 'Делайте домашнее задание вовремя', 'Тренируйтесь хорошо','Ложитесь спать пораньше', 'Помогайте страждущим'];

  return {
    getRandomAdvice: ()=> {
      const index = Math.floor(Math.random()*advicesArray.length);
      return advicesArray[index];
    }
  }
})();


document.getElementById('getAdvice').addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
  document.getElementById('advice').innerText = adviceModule.getRandomAdvice();
});
</script>

<p>
  <h3>Тяжелая атлетика это очень тяжелый спорт!</h3>
</p>
<p>
<i> Список самых сильных атлетов мира</i> </p>
<ol><h1>
<li> Владимир Ильич
<li> Имамбаев Руслан
<li> Рулон Обоев</h1>
</ol>
<h3>Реклама
<a href=url(azino777.ru)>
<br>Жми сюда, чтобы заработать 10000 рублей за час!</h3>
</a>
<p>
<i>Теннис развивает выносливость и координацию.</i>
</p>
<ul><h1>
```

Вот сам сайт.

Comment: Так же надо, что бы контент базы данных выводился

Comment: а где у вас отправка данных на сервер и получаения ответа?

Comment: точно, он же просто не связывается с сервером, как это сделать?

Comment: советую вам посмотреть разные документации по поводу создания свой формы регистрации/авторизации и тд.. и почитать документацию или уроки php.. все запихать в один ответ не получится

Comment: хорошо, тогда как вывести ланные из таблицы myphpadmin? mysql_query("SELECT * FROM регистрационная форма"); не работает

Comment: phpmyadmin - не база данных, а программа для просмотра. База данных называется **mysql**. Функции mysql_query() в РНР уже 3 года как не существует. Остальное в учебниках.

Comment: @Tagmatarch Таблица и поля должны быть на латинице, это не 1С